# Convert iso8601 string date time format to date in Java

Tags: java, date, format

All,

I know I have asked a similar question on parsing an ISO8601 date string into a Date using Java before, but this is a more specific problem using the SimpleDateFormat class.

I have read the article [Wiki ISO8601 Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

I have been supplied an XML file from a customer which has a date and time with the following format:

**2012-08-24T12:15:00+02:00**

According to the Wiki article this is valid which is fair enough.

Given the following code to parse this string, a ParseException is thrown with the message "Unparseable date: "2012-08-24T12:15:00+02:00"".

```
String inputDate = "2012-08-24T12:15:00+02:00";
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date d = sdf.parse(inputDate);
```

The problem is with the colon in the timezone specifier.  +02:00 in the timezone causes the exception to be thrown.  +0200 works fine.

Question is, is it possible to parse this type of string with the SimpleDateFormat?

Thanks

Andez

Comment: you may find this useful: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ISO8601dateparsingutility.htm . It's worth to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, using SimpleDateFormat, parsing this date is not possible (at least not in jdk 6 or lower).  We had to write our own adapter for this ourselves.

Note, since this format is a valid part of XML Schema, you can use the [DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) method to parse this date.

Comment: +1 Better than using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: This is throwing an IllegalArgumentException for me when I try to parse "2015-10-19T18:58:23.000+0000"

Comment: @KimballRobinson - probably because that does not fit the xsd dateTime format (you are missing the ':' in the timezone offset).

Comment: @jtahlborn, I'm getting time stamps from the Salesforce REST api, so I don't control the format.  I am using Joda Time's library to parse the timestamps now.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I have found is on this question.

[Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Quote:
The easier solution is possibly to use the data type converter in JAXB, since JAXB must be able to parse ISO8601 date string according to the XML Schema specification. javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2010-01-01T12:00:00Z") will give you a Calendar object and you can simply use getTime() on it, if you need a Date object.